# What is the best practice for listening to events, group them, and submitting it in batch?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, bigdata

Let's say my system wants to listen to users' click events and save them into the archive storage. I know where the event is coming from (userId - about hundreds of users), and what URL was clicked. (url - infinite variations)

```
class ClickEvent {
  String userId;
  String url;
}
```

If my system is potentially getting thousands of events per second, I do not want to put the massive load into the storage by calling it once per every click event coming in. Assume the storage is an AWS S3-like storage, or data warehouse, where it is good at storing the fewer number of store large files than submitting tens of thousands of requests per second.

My approach currently is.. using GoogleGuava's Cache library. (or just any cache with cache expiration support)

Assume that key for the cache is `userId`, and value for the cache is `List<url>`.

- Cache miss -> Add an entry to the cache `(userId, [url1])`
- Cache hit -> I append new URL to the list `(userId, [url1, url2...])`
- Cache entry expires after configurable X min since the initial write or after having 10000 URLs.
- Upon expiration of entry, I push the data into the storage, ideally, reducing up to 10000 small separate transactions to 1 large transaction.

I am not sure if there is a "standard" or better way (or even a well-known library) to tackle this problem, that is, accumulating thousands of events per second and save them all in the storage/file/data warehouse at once, instead of transferring high tops loads into the downstream services. I feel like this is one of the common use cases for the big data system.

Comment: This is the sort of thing analytics services like [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics) exist to handle. If you need to correlate events with other data you can use reporting apis and/or ETL (extract-transform-load) processes. There aren't many reasons to reinvent this particular wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Google analytics seems to be a fine choice, if I am just interested in app/web activity, but I was using the click event as an example. Actual use cases has nothing to do with user activities. Do you have some examples of 'reporting apis' or platform/libraries?

Comment: Not offhand, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an eventModule class that gets these events and holds them in a queue. Make sure it's a singleton so you can load it from several places in your code:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton

Then I would make these events of a class type and use a factory pattern to create them:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method
This way,  if you need several kinds of events, your singleton will be able to handle them all.

Finally, I would have the eventModule persist these to a local storage every X seconds. Every Y seconds (or Z events in queue) I'd try and send them to a remote storage. If that worked, remove them from the queue.

This will allow you a lot of flexibility in the future when your app grows.